# What is the value of $[c,d]$ when $c$ and $d$ be such that $f(x) ∈ [c, d]$ for all $x ∈ [a, b]$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, derivatives, area

Let $c$ and $d$ be such that $f(x) \in [c, d]$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.

What is the value of $[c,d]$ for the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on the interval $[a, b]=[0,1]$?

I knew taking the minimum and maximum of each term , we can get $c$ and $d$. But how can i split the term of the function here???

Comment: Although it isn't formal, what does the graph look like geometrically?

Comment: @Clayton [The graph looks like parabola](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+sqrt%281-x%5E2%29+on+%5B0%2C1%5D)

Comment: It is actually a quarter circle. I was hoping you'd see this on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is one to one and decreasing in the interval $[0,1]$. So the maximum value of the function is $d=1$ at $x=0$ and minimum value is $c=0$ at $x=1$

Comment: That is , the function is bounded below by $0$ and above by $1$ on the interval $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Yes that is true